# Coverflow android for 3 view at a time

Tags: android, android-viewpager, coverflow

I have to show image carousel in android like -
[image]

In this library or other libraries,what i have found the adjacent view visible partially and rest part covered behind the screen but in my case all part of adjacent view would be covered from center view and partially visible its left/right part.

Using FeatureCoverFlow i partially created this kind of view but apart from left and right view it showing stack of views like -[image]
and sometime it also gives out of memory issue after scrolling.

I have tried 
[FeatureCoverFlow](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow),[FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) and and few others but nothing worked for me.

Comment: What does not work for you? Give some information some code. You can not get an answer like this.

Comment: @mcemilg i have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CarouselLayoutManagerLibrary](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager) has done the work for me.